# Jagged Edges of Brush in Adobe Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, brush, brush-dynamics

I have done a lot of work to resolve the issue, and have even searched for the solution, but no result.

Suddenly I struck with this problem, probably due to some unknown short key combination. Brush in Adobe Photoshop, has become rough edged. Especially when its Hardness is 0, it looks like made up of particles only.

[image]

[image]

Comment: @Luciano thanks for your response. Seems different, still I shall check it in detail.

Comment: The brush size / shape might be different, but the problem / solution is exactly the same.

Comment: Thanks to mention the perfect solution. I actually never used the mode drop down from that top toolbar. Probably that was the reason of this non-sense question.

Comment: Actually, I have been looking for the solution from a long time. As suddenly, problem was solved a long time ago, but once again appeared yesterday. Thank a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Luckily the culprit is right there in your screenshot. Your brush mode is set to `Dissolve`. You should set that to `Normal` instead.

Note that a layer can also have a blend mode "dissolve".

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Joonas for your valuable response. The reason of the question was actually that I always used the Mode for layers. I actually never noticed it exists here also. Thanks a lot.